# Script splits text and adds 1 to value doesnt record the correct number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For the life of me I dont know what is wrong with this code it records the correct number but doesn't add the number correctly unless i type it in myself.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kxIzE_HcPWd82LpGqCXNxg0yczhcnA6yOYRnB4GuAZo/edit?usp=sharing

```
var column = 0;
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("RawData");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows, 1);

  var max = 0;

  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {  
     var splitstring = vals[row][0].toString().split(" ");
 
  
    var splitstring = vals[row][0].toString().split(" ");
    var id = splitstring[1];
    
   Logger.log(id)
    if (max < id) {
      Logger.log(id)
        max = id+1;
         Logger.log(max)
    }
  }
  var LastRow = worksheet.getLastRow();
 
  
 
  worksheet.getRange(LastRow+1,1).setValue("PO# " + max.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, in your script, `var id = splitstring[1];` retrieved by `var splitstring = vals[row][0].toString().split(" ");` is the string type. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var id = splitstring[1];

Logger.log(id)
if (max < id) {
```

#### To:

```
var id = Number(splitstring[1]);
Logger.log(id)
if (max <= id) {
```

#### Note:

- In your script, for example, you might be also able to use `var max = Math.max(...vals.map(([v]) => Number(v.split(" ").pop()))) + 1;` instead of your for loop.

#### Reference:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Nope that didnt work i added a link to what i have for an example it just keeps adding PO# 130

Comment: @Jacob Lenertz Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your sample Spreadsheet, what value do you want to retrieve? Do you want to put the value of `PO# 130`?

Comment: I just want to grab the highest number in the column and add one to it then put the PO# back in front.

Comment: @Jacob Lenertz Thank you for replying. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1):

Tryu this:

```
function myfunk() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("RawData");
  Logger.log(parseInt(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValue().split(' ')[1]) + 1);
}
```